How can I get `make_geocube()` match results from `terra::rast()` when rasterizing a tile represented as a polygon?
I am trying to create a template xarray raster using a perfectly square polygon vector file. The polygon vector file comes from the Landsat Collection 2 Analysis Ready Data tiling scheme (https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-collection-2-us-ard-tile-grid-shapefile-conus). Each row represents a single tile that is 5,000 rows by 5,000 columns at a resolution of 30m.
I can successfully create a 5000x5000 cell SpatRaster in R, but I need a Python solution-- specifically an xarray solution in order to work with the xee package.
In R, this works:
conus_tiles_full <- sf::read_sf(
  paste0(
    "/vsizip/",
    "vsicurl/",
    "https://d9-wret.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/",
    "assets/palladium/production/s3fs-public/atoms/files/",
    "CONUS_C2_ARD_grid.zip/CONUS_C2_ARD_grid/conus_c2_ard_grid.shp"
  )
)

tahoe_tile <- conus_tiles_full |>
  dplyr::filter(h == 3 & v == 8)

r <- terra::rast(tahoe_tile, res = c(30, 30))
r

With the printed details of the r object looking like:
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 5000, 5000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : -2115585, -1965585, 1964805, 2114805  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Albers_Conic_Equal_Area

In Python, I'm trying to use the geocube package to turn a geopandas data.frame into an xarray.
import geopandas
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from geocube.rasterize import rasterize_image

conus_tiles_full = geopandas.read_file("/vsizip/vsicurl/https://d9-wret.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/palladium/production/s3fs-public/atoms/files/CONUS_C2_ARD_grid.zip/CONUS_C2_ARD_grid/conus_c2_ard_grid.shp")
tahoe_tile = conus_tiles_full[(conus_tiles_full.h == 3) & (conus_tiles_full.v == 8)]
ref_grid = make_geocube(
  vector_data=tahoe_tile,
  measurements=[],
  resolution=(-30, 30)
)
ref_grid

Produces this output:
xarray.Dataset

Dimensions:
y: 5001
x: 5001

Coordinates:
y (y) float64 2.115e+06 2.115e+06 ... 1.965e+06

x (x) float64 -2.116e+06 ... -1.966e+06

spatial_ref () int64 0

Data variables: (0)

Indexes: (2)

Attributes: (0)

One thing I notice is that tahoe_tile.geometry.total_bounds shows me xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax that do not appear to match what I see when implemented in R. They are not integers:
array([-2115584.99992983, 1964804.99976929, -1965584.99992983, 2114804.99976929])

It's still 5,000 * 30 = 150,000 meters on each dimension though, so maybe that's not the issue.
I can see that I could specify the bounding box of my output grid in the call to make_geocube() or the output CRS? Maybe that will help?
https://corteva.github.io/geocube/html/geocube.html
